# Android: How to Upload Images from the SD Card

Tags: android

In my application, I want to upload the images from the SD card with restricting the user to upload only less than 2mb.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Use following steps:

1) Use the following intent to open gallery with images:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 101);
```

2) Receive the Uri of selected file in `onActivityResult` func.

```
if (requestCode == 101 && data != null) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
} else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "No Image is selected.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
```

Convert the Uri into a path using following func:

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

After that create a `File` object from the path and then check the size of file:

```
File mFile = new File(path);
int length = mFile.length(); // file size in bytes
```

After that you can simply put an `if-else` to check the file size restriction and then use multi-part upload process for uploading the file.

you can use this [article](http://www.17od.com/2010/02/18/multipart-form-upload-on-android/) for multipart upload.

Comment: please also mark the tick box along with the answer, if you think that answer is correct. THis will help other users when they will be searching for the same problem.